# How to get spring configurations via junit test in spring maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, spring-test

I need to run junit test case.In my controller, i have autowired classes which will be configured during runtime. I need that configurations to be done while running the junit test itself..
Can anyone provide solution for this..

Comment: please add the exception stack trace what you got in console, and also show us how you configured?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code snippet

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:spring-context.xml"})
public class TestClass {
    @Autowired
    private SomeServiceClass service;

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        //  your code goes here
    }
}
```

for spring test dependency you can use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have already used this. When am autowiring a class, that class has some other autowired fields. I have included all autowired class in my test-context.xml. But still some of the classes are not initialized and getting NullPointerException.

Comment: @GowthamShanmugaraj then add the exception what you got in console, and also show us how you configured?

Comment: @GowthamShanmugaraj Maybe some classes are not initialized because you doesn't included their declarations... share with us your configuration and your exception :) in order to help you better